# Easiest way to convert timestamp_ntz to timestamp_tz in Snowflake database

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, timestamp-with-timezone

I have a Timestamp_NTZ column where I know the data are in Central (America/Chicago) timezone. How do I convert it into Timestamp_TZ format during select.

I couldn't just convert to varchar and add timezone offset and back to timestamp_tz because of different offset during daylight saving.

I found following two approaches but they involves more code/typing. Looking for elegant solution.

1. Alter session to the required timezone and use TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ() function. The drawback of this approach is that its two separate query and it cannot be used in stored procedure with run as Owner.

   ```
   alter session set timezone = 'America/Chicago';
   select TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ(column_name) from table_name;
   ```
2. Use TIMESTAMP_TZ_FROM_PARTS function. This involves more typing and looks complicated.

   ```
   select TIMESTAMP_TZ_FROM_PARTS(Year(column_name), Month(column_name), Day(column_name), Hour(column_name), Minute(column_name), Second(column_name), 0, 'America/Chicago') from table_name;
   ```

Is there a simple way to do this in snowflake, something like:

`select TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ(column_name, 'America/Chicago') from table_name;`

Comment: What about converting the [timezone](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/convert_timezone.html) directly?

Comment: The 3 argument version of CONVERT_TIMEZONE returns in TIMESTAMP_NTZ format, which is not what I want.
I can't use 2 argument version because it expect TIMESTAMP_TZ format whereas my data is in TIMESTAMP_NTZ format.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use the [CONVERT_TIMEZONE](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/convert_timezone.html) for this. The 2 argument version Doesn't expect `TIMESTAMP_TZ` as you mentioned in your comment. You can see below that I'm passing in a `TIMESTAMP_NTZ` for demonstration purposes but you could pass in a string like `2020-01-27T08:00:00Z` too if you want:

```sql
select CONVERT_TIMEZONE( 'America/Chicago' , TO_TIMESTAMP_NTZ('2020-01-27T08:00:00Z'));
```

The above returns

`2021-01-26 02:00:00.000000000 -06:00`

Comment: If the 2nd pram is timestamp_ntz, it uses current session time timezone. So if your data is in different timezone than session timezone, then you get wrong data.
If session timezone is 'America/Los_Angeles' and your data is 'America/Chicago':
`select CONVERT_TIMEZONE( 'America/Chicago' , '2020-01-27 08:00:00'::TIMESTAMP_NTZ);` returns
`2020-01-27 10:00:00.000 -0600`

Answer (score 0):

This is a basic workaround that doesn't need messing with the session for the scenario where the input date (from a column) is NTZ and you have the timezone, but not the offset.

Convert_timezone first converts the ntz value to tz in the local timezone of the instance, then converts that to your required timezone. Strip the offset from the converted value and find the difference between that and the original ntz time. Then subtract that difference from the converted value.

- Original value: `'2022-04-28 16:44:35'`
- Expected timezone: `'America/New_York'`
- Converted value: `'2022-04-28T16:44:35-04:00'`

```
SELECT DATEADD(HOUR, -1 * DATEDIFF(HOUR,'2022-04-28 16:44:35'::TIMESTAMP_NTZ,CONVERT_TIMEZONE('America/New_York','2022-04-28 16:44:35')::TIMESTAMP_NTZ),CONVERT_TIMEZONE('America/New_York','2022-04-28 16:44:35'))
```

Unsure if anybody has ever found a better solution or if Snowflake has put something in but I haven't found it.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same issue. Your #2 worked for me. I checked the latest Snowflake docs and don't see anything that would fix it. When you use the 1 parameter CONVERT_TIMEZONE it always moves the time to your local time before adding the timezone name/offset. This is really annoying, Snowflake should add a way to CONVERT_TIMEZONE without affecting the time value otherwise you have to use the convoluted TIMESTAMP_TZ_FROM_PARTS